# angularjs: ng-repeat not working with parent scope property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In a child controller, I'm populating an array on the parent scope:

```
$scope.person.testArray = [{id: "test"},{id: "test2"}];
```

That works fine and the person property now has an extra property called testArray, which contains the above values.

Then in the view associated with the child controller, I want to display the values of the array:

```
<div ng-repeat="op in person.testArray">
  {{op.id}}
</div>
```

Nothing shows up.

However, I know it's related to the fact that I'm using ng-repeat. If, in the child controller I set a regular property on the person object, such as:

```
$scope.person.test = "test";
```

and then in the view I do:

```
{{person.test}}
```

it shows the string "test".

What am I doing wrong with ng-repeat ?

Comment: Do you by chance have a JSFiddle or the like that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Could you try with `op in $parent.person.testArray` instead? `$parent` isn't needed but just give it a shot if it works. Also, could you provide a plunkr or a fiddle where it does not work?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to use `$parent` in your child controller, since the child controller's `$scope` [prototypically inherits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) from the parent controller's `$scope`:

```js
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.person = {};
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.person.testArray = [{id: "test"}, {id: "test2"}];
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="op in person.testArray">{{op.id}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/yhcdM/)</kbd>

Comment: ooh my bad. I don't use $parent in my code. I've added in my post by accident. So I do exactly what you are doing and I still can't display anything in the ng-repeat. I've updated the code in my original post.

Comment: @Sam, we'll need to see more of your code to help you.  You may be using some Angular built-in or custom directives just before or inside the ng-repeat that might be creating additional scopes.

Comment: I've made it work in a separate sample project. I don't know what's wrong in my application, I'll have to investigate further. However, I've noticed in the sample I've made, that instead of updating the parent's property, it creates a new property on the child scope. Is that normal behaviour ? I would have expected the parent scope's property to be updated rather...

Comment: @Sam, without seeing your sample, it is difficult to guess what might be happening.

Answer (score 1):

While like the others I suggest against using $parent, you should be able to use the ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="op in $parent.person.testArray">
  {{op.id}}
</div>
```